# How to start my application after starting of "daemon" process in single script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, background-process

I have a script, that starts my server. I want to start openvpn client before it. Here my current working solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

openvpn --client --config $OVPN_CONFIG &

sleep 10

npm start
```

I want to avoid `sleep` and check openvpn sucessfull running by output line:

`Tue May 14 16:35:50 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed`

How to do that? Note, that this script used as docker container entrypoint.

Comment: Did my solution work for you? If not, I would be happy if you could point out the problems you had with it.

Answer (score 0):

The following bash one-liner runs `openvpn`, waits for the output `Init... Completed`, immediately starts `npm`, and continues to run `openvpn` in the background.

```
#! /bin/bash
grep -qF 'Initialization Sequence Completed' <(openvpn ...) && npm start
```

In case `openvpn` never prints `Init... Completed` the whole command will terminate after `openvpn` terminates without starting `npm`.

Since I have neither `openvpn` nor `npm` installed I use the following functions to emulate their behavior.

```
openvpn() {
  echo "something something"
  sleep 1
  echo "$(date) Initialization Sequence Completed"
  sleep 1
  echo "openvpn still running" >&2 # prints to stderr so that we see it 
}
npm() {
  echo "started npm"
}
```

With these the output of the one-liner from above is

```
started npm
openvpn still running
```